# Ran MrBayes on cluster, but cannot find .con.tre file?

Tags: phylogeny

I am new leaner about phylogeny. currently i ran MrBayes on cluster with whole mtDNA from 101 species.
Phylogenetic analysis were carried out twice separately, once with the third codon position, once were not. InvGAMMA mode for both analysis.
The strange thing is i can get ".con.tre" file with the third codon position input file, but cannot with non-third codon position input file.
i v ran the analysis twice, but still could not get the .con.tre file.
does anyone know why?
here is my .nex file

```
#NEXUS
begin taxa;
dimensions ntax=101;
taxlabels
Ancistrotermes_pakistanicus_Thailand
Blatella_germanica
......
end;

begin characters;
    dimensions nchar=16305;
    format datatype=dna missing=? gap=-;
    matrix
    Ancistrotermes_pakistanicus_Thailand  AAGGAGTTTTATTCTTGC-TT-T...
    ......
;
end;

begin mrbayes;

CHARSET rna12-16S = 1-3141;
CHARSET tRNA = 3142-4875;
CHARSET coding_first = 4876-12495\2;
CHARSET coding_second = 4877-12495\2;

partition favored = 4: rna12-16S, tRNA, coding_first, coding_second;

set partition = favored; 

set autoclose=yes nowarn=yes;

lset applyto=(1,2,3,4) nst=6 rates=invgamma; 

unlink statefreq=(all) revmat=(all) shape=(all) pinvar=(all); 

prset applyto=(all) ratepr=variable;

mcmcp ngen= 10000000 relburnin=yes burninfrac=0.1  printfreq=5000  
samplefreq=5000 nchains=4 savebrlens=yes;

mcmc;

sumt;

end;



#My script on cluster.
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=MrBayes
#SBATCH --partition=compute
#SBATCH --time=6-23
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=15G
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
#SBATCH --mail-type=BEGIN,FAIL,END
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
module load MrBayes.mpi/3.2.3
srun --mpi=pmi2 mb -i test_mrbayes
```

Comment: Show the code you use to run the analysis (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot help you without seeing what you've done.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that! i v show it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a note that does not pertain to the problem directly. The current `CHARSET` command calls every other base, but a codon is 3 bp long. To sample every first and second codon position, the code must read:

```
CHARSET coding_first = 4876-12495\3;
CHARSET coding_second = 4877-12495\3;
```

The analysis must be repeated with the changed partition setting.

The `SUMT` command seems fine and should have summarised the result. To run the summary on a desktop computer, comment the `mcmc` command and execute the nexus file again. The folder from where you will execute the commands should include the results sampled trees in the `*.t` files.

```
[all the code above deleted for clarity of the change]
mcmcp ngen= 10000000 relburnin=yes burninfrac=0.1  printfreq=5000  
samplefreq=5000 nchains=4 savebrlens=yes;

[mcmc;]

sumt;

end;
```